# React Router V4 - Route not loading correct component

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I've just migrated from router v2 to v4 and I have an issue. I can't figure out what's wrong.

So I have a main component that loads the page basically

```
<HashRouter>
  <Route
    path="/"
    render={(props) => <App pageOptions={options} routeProps={props} />}
  />
</HashRouter>, appNode);
```

And then inside the `App` I have a `Switch`

```
<Switch>
  <Route
     exact
     path="/"
     render={() =>
        <Main
          options={this.props.pageOptions}
          {...this.state}
        />
     }
  />
  <Route
     path="/page/:id(/?)"
     render={() =>
       <Content
         options={this.props.pageOptions}
         {...this.state}
       />
     }
  />
</Switch>
```

I enter the page and the root Route works fine but when I try to access let's say this url `/page/345` it still shows the `Main` components and not the `Content` one.

What am I missing here?

Comment: I haven't used `HashRouter` before as some kind of a newbie, but `/#/page/123` works in your case. Isn't that the expected behavior with `HashRouter`?

Comment: @devserkan that's what I'm trying to achieve, but it's not loading anything.

Comment: You mean `/#/page/123` does not load anything or `/page/123`?

Comment: /#/page/123 I ment

Comment: Drop the `(/?)` part in your path.

Answer (score 0):

Is there any particular reason why you are using hashRouter.
If you replace it with BrowserRouter, it should work.

More info : https://medium.com/@djoepramono/react-router-4-gotchas-2ecd1282de65

Comment: I'm running a Single Page Application. That's why I'm using the HashRouter

Comment: You can also use `BrowserRouter` in your SPA. Actually, most of the time people use `BrowserRouter`.

Comment: Oh, didn't know that. I'll try it and come back with an answer